# After updating - cordova doesn't fire deviceready event

Tags: cordova

After updating cordova, platforms, java, node and android version I get

```
cordova.js:1223 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

Code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("READY");
}
```

Also this doesn't work:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown(){
    console.log("backbutton pressed");
}
```

A little more info:

```
cordova version: 6.4.0
node: 7.0.0 
Installed platforms:
   android 6.0.0
   browser 4.1.0
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

and installed plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.1.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.2 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.4 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.istablet 1.1.0 "Is Tablet"
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem too. Please try this.

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-device<br>
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-network-information<br>
cordova run android
```

Your App will not run correctly. But your App will receive deviceready event.

As far as I know, cordova-plugin-file also prevent deviceready event. And others.

```
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview: OK
com.borismus.webintent: OK
cordova-plugin-admobpro: OK
```

**SOLVED**: Just install newest plugins.

Plugins Release - Apache Cordova
https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/09/14/plugins-release.html

Answer (score 0):

This is from outdated plugin. Install all updates.